# Run an infinite loop in the backgroung in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I would like the code to run in the background and to update my GUI periodically. How can I accomplish this?

For example, suppose I want to execute something like this in the background of the GUI code you can see below:

```
x = 0

while True:
   print(x)
   x = x + 1
   time.sleep(1)
```

This is the GUI code:

```
class GUIFramework(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master.title("Volume Monitor")
        self.grid(padx=10, pady=10,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.CreateWidgets()

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        textOne = Entry(self, width=2)
        textOne.grid(row=1, column=0)

        listbox = Listbox(self,relief=SUNKEN)
        listbox.grid(row=5,rowspan=2,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky=N+W+S+E,pady=5)
        listbox.insert(END,"This is an alert message.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiFrame = GUIFramework()
    guiFrame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a little unclear what your code at the top is supposed to do, however, if you just want to call a function every second (or every the amount of seconds you want), you can use the [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) method.

So, if you just want to do something with `textOne`, you'd probably do something like:

```
...
textOne = Entry(self, width=2)
textOne.x = 0

def increment_textOne():
    textOne.x += 1

    # register "increment_textOne" to be called every 1 sec
    self.after(1000, increment_textOne)
```

You could make this function a method of your class (in this case I called it `callback`), and your code would look like this:

```
class Foo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.x = 0
        self.id = self.after(1000, self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        self.x += 1
        print(self.x)
        #You can cancel the call by doing "self.after_cancel(self.id)"
        self.id = self.after(1000, self.callback)  

gui = Foo()
gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to run a distinct infinite loop you have no choice but to use a separate thread, and communicate via a thread safe queue. However, except under fairly unusual circumstances you should never need to run an infinite loop. Afte all, you already have an infinite loop running: the event loop. So, when you say you want an infinite loop you are really asking how to do an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.

@mgilson has given a good example on how to do that using `after`, which you should consider trying before trying to use threads. Threading makes what you want possible, but it also makes your code considerably more complex.