# Tkinter and thread. out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm experimenting with Tkinter and the threads mechanism. Can anyone explain why this raises the exception:

```
<class '_tkinter.TclError'> out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

and how can I solve this? Below is the code. BTW, I know some people suggest to use the threading module instead of thread, but for now I'd like to use the thread module which is simpler just to introduce myself to the mechanism.

```
from Tkinter import *
import thread
import time

def main_thread(master):

    try:
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side='bottom')
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')

        t = "Title"
        title = StringVar()
        title.set(t)
        ttl = Label(master, textvariable=title, font=("Helvetica", 18))
        ttl.pack(side='top')
        cont = Text(master, font=("Helvetica",14), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        cont.pack(side='bottom')
        button = Button(frame,text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
        button.pack(side='bottom')

        n = 0
        while 1:
            n += 1
            cont.insert('end', str(n)+"\n")
            time.sleep(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print type(e), e

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.title("My counting application")
    thread.start_new_thread(main_thread, (root,)) # FIXME: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you,
Luca

---

EDIT

I solved substituting

```
    n = 0
    while 1:
        n += 1
        cont.insert('end', str(n)+"\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

with

```
    n = 0
    def do_every_second(n):
        cont.insert("end", str(n) + "\n")
        n += 1
        master.after(1000, do_every_second, n)
    do_every_second(n)
```

and calling

```
main_thread(root)
```

instead of

```
thread.start_new_thread(main_thread, (root,))
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand the -1. In my humble opinion, this is a good question for people who doesn't know the answer already. Probably it may appear naive to people who are experts or at least master the basics of threads and Tkinter, but these are my very first lines with Tkinter and thread, and other people may end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of fatal flaws in your code. For one, you simply can't write code that touches tkinter widgets from more than one thread. You are creating the root window in the main thread, so you can only ever directly access widgets from the main thread. Tkinter is not thread safe.

The second problem is that you have an infinite loop that is constantly appending to the text widget. It has no choice but to eventually run out of memory.

To solve your problem you should:

1. not have an infinite loop that forever appends to the text widget
2. not access any widgets from more than a single thread

If you want to run a function once a second, there are better ways to do that than with threads. In short:

```
def do_every_second():
    cont.insert("end", str(n) + "\n")
    root.after(1000, do_every_second)
```

This will cause do_every_second to do whatever it does, then arranges for itself to be called again one second in the future.

Comment: I edited my original question to include a possible solution based on your suggestion. Anyway, I don't completely get why my code didn't work.
You say:
  1) an infinite loop that forever appends to the text widget, make it runs out of memory.
  I understand up to a point because I'm appending things slowly (once every second) but it runs out of memory really fast.
  2) "you simply can't write code that touches tkinter widgets from more than one thread."
  I'm not really sure which threads are the two threads you are mentioning. I see only one thread.

Can  you please give me more info?

Comment: @the_eraser: the two threads are the main thread (the one that creates the instance of `Tk`), and the other thread which you called "main".

Comment: i never thought creating the root window in the main thread and accessing it on another thread would be the cause of my problem, after moving it to the other thread, everything works!

Answer (score -1):

The error is correct - there's an infinite loop on one of the `tkinter` elements. The `thread` module has nothing to do with it. The specific line causing the error:

```
cont.insert('end', str(n)+"\n")
```

Since `cont` is a tkinter element, you can not run it in your infinite while loop. To do what you want, you would need to print to the console instead. This can be demonstrated if you replace the offending line with a simple:

```
print(str(n)+"\n")
```

Edit: If you truly want to achieve the same effect you originally intended, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214701/tkinter-loop-with-python) deals with a potential alternative.

Edit2: I would assume the exception is a design choice by the `tkinter` library (although I'm no expert). This would make sense since `tkinter` already uses an infinite loop for its event loop. I would imagine an infinite loop would prevent `tkinter` from ever drawing the changes to the screen and instead the libraries authors chose to throw an exception instead. A `print` should work since there's nothing new to draw, plus it's in it's own thread allowing `tkinter`'s event loop to continue.

Comment: Why can he use print but not use cont.insert? What does calling them in an infinite loop have to do with whether you can call them or not? Your answer will be better if you explain a bit more.

Comment: @ubomb Sorry for my late reply. Of course the error is correct, it's my fault... I didn't believe for a second that was a bug or something :D. Changing cont.insert('end', str(n)+"\n") with print(str(n)+"\n"), it keeps on not working. Even commenting out both doesn't solve the problem. Removing the while loop completely keeps raising the exception.