# tcl: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Tags: .net, r, r.net

I am using R.net and trying to call a function written in R.

This is my code in visual studio

```
var myfnc = _engine.Evaluate("source('.....CalculateCost.R')").AsCharacter();

var _uid = _engine.CreateCharacter(uid);
var arr = _engine.CreateIntegerVector(ids.Length);
var _batchGuid = _engine.CreateCharacter(batchId);

var ss = _engine.Evaluate(myfnc[0]).AsFunction();
ss.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { arr, _uid, _batchGuid });

//_engine has been initialized in the constructor
```

The above code will generate a plot and will save in a folder. Thats it.

Problem: It works good most of the times. But sometimes it throws the following error.

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
[tcl] out of stack space (infinite loop?).
 at RDotNet.Function.evaluateCall(IntPtr call)
at RDotNet.Function.createCallAndEvaluate(IntPtr argument)
at RDotNet.Function.InvokeOrderedArguments(SymbolicExpression[] args)
at RDotNet.Closure.Invoke(SymbolicExpression[] args)
at SmartPoolApp.Helpers.RStuffGenerator.ExecuteCostCalculation(Int32[] ids,    String uid, String batchId) in k:\Repositories\myprogram\Helpers\RStuffGenerator.cs:line 157
```

in the line:57, I have this code:

```
ss.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { arr, _uid, _batchGuid });
```

I just don't know how to solve it and what does it even mean!!
any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I am running this from an asp.net mvc web app. It works first time and when I refresh couple of times, it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that R.NET is in the mix may be a contributing factor, but this is probably not the core of the issue, if at all.

Two things I note:

- It works most of the time, but sometimes not
- Something to do with stack space (in the context of using R)

The first point hints at the possibility of issues with multi-threading, notoriously non-reproducible and apparently random. So does the second, but this is not obvious and a quirk of R.

Do you have a reason to think something in your code, somewhere, is multi-threaded? this is something you may not do explicitly yourself. For instance, are you running this from the command line, windows forms, Web application?

This [post on R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-March/068702.html) gives some information on the interplay of R CStackLimit and multi-threading.

This post [Tkinter and thread. out of stack space (infinite loop?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541693/tkinter-and-thread-out-of-stack-space-infinite-loop) on stackoverflow relates experience with some tcl/tk stuff and errors if multiple threads access it.

Comment: thanks for writing. I have added couple of lines in the question. I have gone through your links, but i am not sure what to do or what to change.

Comment: Hi. this line you wrote "Do you have a reason to think something in your code, somewhere, is multi-threaded?"..I have investigated and found out when I try to access the R calculation part from multiple browsers and hit refresh too many times, it breaks. so what I did is, added some threading /Semaphore in my .net code and looks like the error doesn't come again with the same kind of test.