# Python: Execute callback method in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Not wanting my GUI to freeze, I've decided to use a thread for a file operation. Currently I'm using `thread.start_new_thread(self.openFile, (filepath, self.openedFile))` to do so, with `self.openedFile` being my callback method. Inside `self.openFile` it is just invoked using `callback(success)`.

But unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to execute my callback in the main thread instead of the newly created one. This is required as the GUI cannot be modified from another thread.

I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread owning the GUI will have to periodically check a `Queue.Queue` instance on which other threads can put work requests (e.g a callback function and arguments for it).

How easy or hard it is to insert such checks within a GUI's main loop is 100% dependent on exactly what GUI framework you're using.

For example if you're using Tkinter, the `after` method of widgets lets you do such periodic checks, as explained e.g at [Run an infinite loop in the backgroung in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214701/tkinter-loop-with-python) .

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the PyQT equivalent to Tkinter's after? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I believe QTimer is what you'd use, http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QTimer.html .