# Reading serial input and printing to Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter based GUI for an Arduino printing sensors value and responding to user input.

The code I'm trying to use to eliminate while loops is this, which doesn't print any sensor information, the only output is "Trying.../dev/ttyACM0" followed by the tkinter window opening.
    import serial
    import time
    from Tkinter import *

```
connected = False
write_to_file_path = "output.txt"
output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "w+")

locations=['/dev/ttyACM0','/dev/ttyACM1','/dev/ttyACM2','/dev/ttyACM3']

for device in locations:
    try:
        print "Trying...",device
        ser = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
        break
    except:
        print "Failed to connect on",device

## loop until the arduino tells us it is ready
while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True

time.sleep(0.1)
ser.flushInput()
time.sleep(1)

def serialRead():
    if ser.inWaiting():
        line = ser.readline()
        data = line.decode("utf-8").split('\t')
        print(data)
        output_file.write(line)
        root.after(1000, serialRead)



root = Tk()
root.title("Temperature Control")
serialRead()
root.mainloop()
```

This, on the other hand, works perfectly with the exception of not having a tkinter window. But it removes old input from the buffer and reads in the new input.

```
import serial
import time

connected = False
write_to_file_path = "output.txt"
output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "w+")

serial_port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud_rate = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=5)
time.sleep(0.1)
ser.flushInput()
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    if ser.inWaiting():
        line = ser.readline()
        data = line.decode("utf-8").split('\t') #ser.readline returns a binary, convert to string
        print data[0] + '\t' + data[1]
        output_file.write(line)
```

This was inspired by a different stackoverflow post from a while ago: [Run an infinite loop in the backgroung in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214701/run-an-infinite-loop-in-the-backgroung-in-tkinter)

I've seen some example using threading but I don't know much about python nor threading so I'd really like to get it to work with root.after() if that's possible. I've also tried the example using root.after, all of which are pretty similar to the one I linked, and I couldn't get any of them working. Am I doing anything obviously wrong or in a way that's much more difficult than it needs to be? I would appreciate it greatly if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: `ser = serial.Serial(device, 9600, timeout=5)` might solve your problem ... my guess is is that the raspbery pi is opening the AMA0 port (its GPIO port) and since theres nothing to read... the `read()` just hangs forever waiting for bytes that wont come... as an aside you will want to use threading ... for sure

Comment: The Arduino is sending data once every like 100ms so there's definitely something to read. Just tried the revision and it didn't make a difference. Why is threading necessary? This gui doesn't have to do more than read data and once in a while send a byte, so I figured maximizing computational efficiency isn't super critical?

Comment: because if you are in the main thread it blocks when you are doing queries ... and it will not feel right ...

Comment: Okay, I'll try to see if I can figure out how to do this via threading instead then. Thanks

Comment: its probably fine for proof of concept to jest get it working ... but you will want the serial stuff in its own thread soonish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a UI in TK for reading data from a GPS receiver and I had difficulties getting root.mainloop() to run, so instead I put a callback inside the TK app that ends up calling root.update() rather than mainloop.

The code looks something like this:

```
class App:

def __init__(self, master):
    self.sats = tk.StringVar()
    self.satsnum = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.sats, bg="blue")
    self.satsnum.pack()

def update_display(self, master):

    while source:

        self.sats.set(n_sats)

        if n_sats < 10:
            satsbgcolor = 'red'
        else:
            satsbgcolor = 'green'
        self.satsnum.configure(bg = satsbgcolor)

        master.update()
        time.sleep(1)


with serial_link.get_base_args_driver(args) as driver:
    with Handler(Framer(driver.read, driver.write, verbose=True)) as source:
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = App(root)
        app.update_display(root)
```

Note, the time.sleep(1) is necessary on MacOS as tk.update() will leak memory if the update is called too fast.