# Exception in Tkinter callback,TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

```
from tkinter import *

from time import sleep

import random                        

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, x, y, xspeed, yspeed):
        self.canvas = canvas 
        self.color = color 
        self.size = size 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 
        self.xspeed = xspeed 
        self.yspeed = yspeed
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+size,y+size,fill=color)
    def move(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        (x1, y1, x2, y2)=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        (self.x, self.y)=(x1, y1)
        if x1<=0 or x2>=WIDTH:         
            self.xspeed=-self.xspeed
        if y1<=0 or y2>=HEIGHT:
            self.yspeed=-self.yspeed

WIDTH=800

HEIGHT=400

bullets=[]

def fire(event):

    bullets.append(Ball(canvas, 10, "red", 100, 200, 10, 0))


window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)

canvas.pack()

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", fire)


spaceship = Ball(canvas, "green", 100, 100, 200, 0, 0)

enemy = Ball(canvas, "red", 100, 500, 200, 0, 5)


while True:

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.move()
        if (bullet.x+bullet.size) >= WIDTH:
            canvas.delete(bullet.id)
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    enemy.move()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.03)
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\qldhv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:/Users/qldhv/Desktop/컴사문/13/ㅇㅇ.py", line 29, in fire
> bullets.append(Ball(canvas, 10, "red", 100, 200, 10, 0))
> File "C:/Users/qldhv/Desktop/컴사문/13/ㅇㅇ.py", line 14, in **init**
> self.id=canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+size,y+size,fill=color)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

An error occurs when i click. I don’t' know the reason

Comment: `Ball(canvas, 10, "red"` has mixed up arguments. Note the order defined in `Ball`'s `__init__`. It's color then size, not size then color. That means you're attempting to do `x + "red"`, which causes an error.

Comment: @이정모 You shouldn't use `while True` loops or `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215725/11106801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the `Ball` is

```
def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, x, y, xspeed, yspeed):
```

So we have to pass the arguments in this particular order while creating an instance from the contractor `Ball()`

**Check out this line**

```
 bullets.append(Ball(canvas, 10, "red", 100, 200, 10, 0))
```

Here you actually passed `size="red` and `color=10`, so the Balls instance created by this line now has `int` as `color` and `str` as `size`

**It should be**

```
bullets.append(Ball(canvas, "red", 10, 100, 200, 10, 0))
```

Otherwise, you could use

```
bullets.append(Ball(canvas=canvas, size=10, color="red", x=100, x=200, xspeed=10, yspeed=0))
```